# How to show post only to logged in user in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Okay guys, I am fairly new to rails. I have successfully created a rails app that stores login information for you. I used devise for the user management and installed cancan but no idea how to use it.

Anyways,

Right now, not matter if you are logged in or not, the site shows you all the "post" or "entrees" that have been entered by any user. I need a way to restrict this to only show post that were made by the user that is currently logged in.

I have found through research that I need do something here:

```
class FtpLoginsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_ftp_login, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /ftp_logins
  # GET /ftp_logins.json
  def index
    @ftp_logins = FtpLogin.all
  end

  # GET /ftp_logins/1
  # GET /ftp_logins/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /ftp_logins/new
  def new
    @ftp_login = FtpLogin.new
  end

  # GET /ftp_logins/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /ftp_logins
  # POST /ftp_logins.json
  def create
    @ftp_login = FtpLogin.new(ftp_login_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ftp_login.save
        format.html { redirect_to @ftp_login, notice: 'Ftp login was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @ftp_login }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @ftp_login.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /ftp_logins/1
  # PATCH/PUT /ftp_logins/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ftp_login.update(ftp_login_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @ftp_login, notice: 'Ftp login was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @ftp_login.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /ftp_logins/1
  # DELETE /ftp_logins/1.json
  def destroy
    @ftp_login.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to ftp_logins_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_ftp_login
      @ftp_login = FtpLogin.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def ftp_login_params
      params.require(:ftp_login).permit(:client_name, :website_name, :ftp_login, :ftp_password, :notes)
    end
end
```

If someone could please send me in the right direction here that would be fantastic!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for that you first have to make ensure that user is logged in before it goes to your action . so you need a before filter for that . authenticate_user! is a method given by devise . so if a user is not logged in he will redirect to the sign in page automatically

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:posts, :entries]
```

for collecting the posts of a specific user

```
@posts = current_user.posts
```

or if it is coming for show a particular post you can do

```
@post = current_user.posts.where(id: params[:id])
```

Comment: Okay, this is what I have..

class FtpLoginsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_ftp_login, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:show]
  # GET /ftp_logins
  # GET /ftp_logins.json
  def index
    (@)ftp_login = current_user.FtpLogin
    (@)ftp_logins = FtpLogin.all
  end


I had to add (@) for it to accept in the comment.
Is this correct?

Comment: can you  paste the relation you made between FtpLogin and User model

Comment: Is there a way to contact you directly?

Comment: nitinjain2021 is my skype handle . but i am not available on that today

Answer (score 0):

You can use `before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:posts, :entries]` to restrict only the logged in user to view these actions.

To restrict users to view only posts created by them, you can create your own filter like

```
def check_user
  redircet_to :back, notice: "Restricted area!" if current_user.posts.include?(@post)
end
```

Comment: what are you expecting from current_user.posts.include?(@post) . can you explain that

Comment: This filter can be used in actions like update, edit, show...when we have `@post` variable already set in a filter like `find_post`.

Comment: first thing when this filter run you will get 500 error if user is not logged in

Comment: Add this filter after `authenticate_user!`